# Querying model based on complex relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am very new to Laravel and Eloquent and I am trying to define a data model a fetch records from it.

I have following tables

- **user**
- **task**

  - user_id
- **tasks_state**

  - user_id
  - task_id
  - state

Basically each user can create multiple tasks and each task belongs to exactly one user. Then each task can have multiple task states for each user that interacted with it. (Like task viewed (by other user) or similarly)

I defined the Models as following:

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Model {
    public function tasksState(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TaskState');
    }
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }
}
```

**Task Model**

```
class Task extends Model {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function tasksState(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TaskState');
    }
}
```

**Task State Model**

```
class TaskState extends Model {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
    }
}
```

Then when I insert a task state, I do it as following: (Is this correct?)

```
$task_viewed = new TaskState();
$task_viewed->state = $state;
$task_viewed->user_id = $user->id;

$task->tasksState()->save($task_viewed);
```

Now, I am facing an issue, how to fetch all tasks for a particular user that were not created by him and he has not interacted with them - either no record in tasks_state table or the task state == 0.

I am also thinking that maybe the relations between models are not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
$tasks = Task::where('user_id', '<>', $userId)
             ->whereDoesntHave('tasksState', function($q) use($userId) {
                 $q->where('user_id', $userId)->where('state', 0);
             })->get();
```

Comment: Should not it be possible to do this as one database query instead of two? It just seems a bit inefficient...

Comment: The second solution looks more like what I am looking for :-) There is still one more question though. I am thinking now that the way I defined the models should have rather been many to many in case of tasks_state table. Don't you think so? Also would it facilitate the solution? I just saw an example with 'pivot' eloquent function.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your data structure is, so I can't tell for sure, but it looks like many-to-many relation where `tasks_state` is a pivot table. If user can interact with many tasks and every task has many users, then it's many-to-many.

Comment: Ok, let's consider it was many to many, would there be a different way how to query it?

Comment: Because of "or the task state == 0" you should add the condition `->where('state', '<>', 0)` within the closure.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thanks, I've missed `state` part. I guess in this case it should be `->orWhere('state', 0);`, but maybe I misunderstood the question. user3559787, can you test the code and tell us if it's correct please.

Comment: Was just coming back to accept your answer :-) It is working as intended! Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin - With `orWhere('state', 0)` you will create `where user_id = ? or state = 0`. That will include all task_states with `state=0` regardless of `user_id`. Thus `whereDoesntHave` will allways "return" `false` if there is any entry with `state=0` in the table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, but I'm using `whereDoesntHave()`, not `whereHas()` here, so it should be `state = 0`, I guess.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - You are right that there has to be 'where' and not 'orWhere' in order for it to work.

Comment: Yes.. but it should be `<> 0` :-)

Comment: @user3559787, thanks for feedback, I've fixed the code.